# Multilist with search display results without Template name

Tags: content-editor, fieldtype

I used the multilist with search and it works fine, but the results return the items and (Template name), and I want to return items name only without template name.
is there any way to do that?

my query :

```
StartSearchLocation={C4B71DF5-3567-4458-8084-FBA73D5D1FB2}&Filter=+section_s:{C1D3DDBA-BD6F-4245-A5A7-2E3FED1D8B78}|+category_s:{39C14AB9-66F1-4CFC-B10C-BEC115F4086B}|+_language:en&TemplateFilter:{7D55B79F-E3F6-494C-8561-31E27D60B6F7}&SortField=__smallupdateddate[desc]
```

---

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly , you need the results to be displayed without the template names (in brackets).
Unfortunately, this is a OOTB feature in Sitecore Multilist search field type. You will need to override the field and use the below code.

```
public override string OutputString(Item item)  
{
     Item bucketItemOrParent = ItemExtensions.GetParentBucketItemOrParent(item);
     string str = bucketItemOrParent != null ? "- " + bucketItemOrParent.DisplayName : string.Empty;
     return string.Format("{0} ({1} {2})", item.DisplayName, item.TemplateName, str);
}
```

Code referenced from - https://blog.rauljimenez.co.uk/multlistfield-search/. Remove the ( ) in the String.Format link as per requirement.

Comment: Thank you, it's working fine with selected items, and still same problem with unselect items

Answer (score 4):

Since this is the OOTB feature of the Sitecore so I will **not recommend** changing in it but if you just want to update the UI of the `multilist with search` field so that content author not see the template name then you can simply update the `BucketList.js` file located in `\sitecore\shell\Controls\BucketList` under your website. In this file you need to update the constructor for request success handler, see the commented line in below code -

```
self.SuccessHandler = function (multilist) {
    return function (request) {
        var response = eval(request.responseText);
        multilist.options.length = 0;
        multilist.removeClassName('loadingItems');

        var itemIdsHash = {};
        var reducedItems = [];
        var i;
        var item;
        for (i = 0; i < response.items.length; i++) {
            item = response.items[i];

            if (!itemIdsHash[item.ItemId]) {
                itemIdsHash[item.ItemId] = true;
                reducedItems[reducedItems.length] = item;
            }
        }

        for (i = 0; i < reducedItems.length; i++) {
            item = reducedItems[i];
            //multilist.options[multilist.options.length] = new Option((item.DisplayName || item.Name) + ' (' + item.TemplateName + (item.Bucket && (' - ' + item.Bucket)) + ')', item.ItemId);
            multilist.options[multilist.options.length] = new Option((item.DisplayName || item.Name), item.ItemId);
        }

        self.pageNumber = response.PageNumbers;
        self.currentPage = response.CurrentPage;
        $('pageNumber' + self.clientId).innerHTML = self.format(self.of, self.currentPage, self.pageNumber);
    };
};
```

You just need to remove `+ ' (' + item.TemplateName + (item.Bucket && (' - ' + item.Bucket)) + ')'` line.

Comment: Many thanks, it's work fine 1oo % and solved my problem ... thank you

Comment: Consider source control this script, so that Sitecore upgrade should not break this feature.

Answer (score 0):

You can also take a look at my project which uses a much better UI for searching (the same that you normally get with buckets): https://github.com/Barsonax/SitecoreSearchFields